# High(er than 30 Hz) refresh rate PS/2-to-USB adapter for a ***new*** PC

Tags: usb, conversion, adapter, ps2

I'm part of the 1%. The keyboard snobs.

I use a 16-year-old keyboard.  It's made by [Alps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huCdi0bljgk), with all the hullabaloo to do with their key-switches.  Interestingly enough, it also has an Alps Glidepoint pad attached.

I have fallen in love and cannot stop using this. I even continue to seek out replacements for the time when it fails completely, but I am faced with a dilemma.

My new PC has ***one*** [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) port.  Every USB connected PS/2 port adapter seems to run abysmally slow, to the order of 30 Hz when using 'evhz' as found on the [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) wiki for the mouse polling rate: "event6: latest hz = 31 (average hz = 31)"

I've tried the "Cheshen" chip dongle adapters. I've got an old [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) which seems to work better/more reliably, but it is just as slow. Its listed as an EzKEY Corp. USB-to-PS/2 Adapter v1.09.

I want something that I can use entirely reliably, and it comes down to the scan rate of the conversion algorithm. I fill up whatever buffer exists in the PS/2 controller of the thing, because the pad is extremely high [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch).  I can cross 1600 pixels in one fell swoop and still have the precision to do simple graphic editing without moving for the mouse.

Is there a better/faster/stronger PS/2-to-USB adapter?  Does a PS/2 to PCI one exist, that doesn't involve a USB controller intermediary?  I want a full proper 200 Hz secondary PS/2 port!

Comment: We don't really do product suggestions on Stack Exchange websites.  I am going to guess you will need to wait until there are USB3 to PS2 connectors on the market.

Comment: Ramhound is right about the no shopping suggestions. Having said that, as one of those 1% snobs I am also curious. (Written from my IBM model M, produced in 1991)

Comment: There is an unwritten rule about shopping questions for obscure things being on-topic. The thing is: We don't want questions about "which graphics card should I buy?" but this seems a little more specialized, in the sense of, "does this exist?".

Comment: "Every USB connected PS/2 port adaptor seems to run abysmally slow" .. "Does anyone make a better".   Which ones have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=19841.0) (from 2011) on GeekHack implies that there aren't any easy-to-find faster converters.  The post's claim that "most people will never use it so most manufacturers don't waste time developing it" sounds likely to me, and the claim that many PS/2 PCI add-in cards are just an on-board USB-PS/2 converter sounds likely as well.

However, if the port on your new computer is one that can be used with either a mouse or a keyboard, you may be able to use a PS/2 splitter designed for old laptops with only one port.  Note that this is almost definitely not officially supported, but PS/2 splitters for old laptops can be found cheaply online, so it probably can't hurt to try.